# Good tutorial on org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Can someone give a good suggestions of an excellent tutorial on org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

I tried this one but it does not cover a lot of details about the params etc.

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/tutorial/html/ seems a little more elaborate.

Comment: did you want v3 in particular? @The MYYN's link is the official link for v4.

Comment: oh, not sure actually because in Android it is a built in library.  I just checked and I a pretty sure it is version 4

Answer (score 3):

[Apache HttpClient - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html) has examples using params

> The following will send a post request to the URL "http://vogellac2dm.appspot.com/register" and include a parameter "registrationid" which an random value.